# Recursive Functions - Two Functions or Last Optional Parameter

Tags: language-agnostic, recursion, naming-conventions

When writing recursive functions, it sometimes happens that something should happen only on the first pass of the recursive algorithm. When this is true, I have two options,

1. Have an optional parameter called "first run" which is set to true by default but when called recursively, the argument is false
2. Have two functions

Which option is preferable? If it is the latter, what should I name these functions? (e.g. if its a flood fill algorithm would I choose `FloodFill` and `FloodFillRecursive`?)

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might use two functions, and I would say that the function that will be called should be named `FloodFill` : the user doesn't need to know how that function is implemented, so it should not be named `FloodFillRecursive`.

Actually, `FloodFillRecursive` could be the name of the *inner* function : the one that contains the implementation, the on that is called by the one called by the user -- as it is that second function that is recursive.

Ideally, that function should not be visible from the users : it should be kind of hidden in your library *(be it trully hidden, or using some naming-convention that informs users they should not call it directly)*.

And, this way, if you change implementation, you will not have your users call a `FloodFillRecursive` function that might no be recursive anymore.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking - I was just checking I was using best practices. I will leave this question open to see if I get any other responses. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2):

It would depend really if the function is intended to be usable by 3rd party developers. If it is it might be preferable to use the two functions approach for neatness's sake, with the second function (FloodFillRecursive) private/internal to your library.

If it's not then the optional parameter approach is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 is better in every case I can think of. This depends on the language you're using, but you're probably going to see significantly more (entirely avoidable) overhead by passing an additional argument every time.

For the naming convention, use a normal name for the outer function (eg FloodFill). For the inner function I'd say FloodFillRecursive or FloodFillInner are good choices.

Answer (score 2):

If the language allows it then in my opinion the best is to have one function with the official "clean" interface, and the using a local function (not visible outside) for the recursion.

For example in Common Lisp

```
(defun n-queens (n)
    (let ((result (list)))
      (labels ((place-queen (row free-cols free-diagonals free-counter-diagonals)
                  ...))
        (place-queen 0 ...)
        result)))
```

or Python

```
def n_queens(n):
    result = []
    def place_queen(row, free_cols, free_diags, free_counter_diags):
        ...
    place_queen(0, ...)
    return result
```

in the above example the recursive functions requires many parameters (e.g. the still free columns, diagonals and counter-diagonals) but the official public function only accepts a parameter and the recursion is handled internally.